# Google Login popup windows doesn't allow me to select google account to google signup in firefox browser on Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon

Tags: firefox, popup, google-signin, linux-mint

When I aim to login with google account with a chrome browser it shows a popup and allows me to choose with which account I would like to login. But When I do the same with a Firefox browser just shows a popup window for a few secs and disappears. Yes Firefox also logins successfully but with only one google account where I can not choose any account. I want Firefox to act like a chrome browser in this case. Thanks in advance